# UnityException: Speech recognition is not supported on this machine

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, speech-recognition, voice-recognition

I am working on game with voice command recognition. Unity 2021.3.29f1, Windows 11. I have read multiple questions with this problem but nothing seems to work for me. I have English (US) laguage selected as prime language, Get to know me in "Privacy/Speech, Inking, & Typing", speach access is enabled and correctly working in system. Microphone is added in unity player settings and correctly detected in code. I am not sure what else I could miss. Some answers were hinting on enabling Cortana but on Win 11 it is deprecated.

> UnityException: Speech recognition is not supported on this machine.
> UnityEngine.Windows.Speech.KeywordRecognizer..ctor (System.String[] keywords, UnityEngine.Windows.Speech.ConfidenceLevel minimumConfidence) (at <91dc399f41a440558c716315c7e834ab>:0)
> UnityEngine.Windows.Speech.KeywordRecognizer..ctor (System.String[] keywords) (at <91dc399f41a440558c716315c7e834ab>:0)